# Ajuda para configurar Servidor ToyVpn Android

Tags: android, ubuntu, linux, vpn

Olá, tenho um problema e já estou há 3 dias procurando uma solução, espero que alguém me possa ajudar.

Estou tentando testar o exemplo do Android ToyVpn, mas não estou a ter sucesso nas configurações do servidor. O arquivo do servidor informa vários IPS para modificação mas eu não sei como configurar.

Meu ambiente de trabalho é o seguinte:

Tenho um servidor VPS onde está rodando o Ubunto, é nele que quero instalar o servidor. Nas configurações de `ifconfig` tenho as seguintes configurações:

```
IP interno 10.0.239.17
Bcast 10.0.255.255
Mask 255.255.0.0
```

meu IP público do VPS é `54.174.69.244`.

Já desativei o Firewall do VPS para testes, mas sem sucesso. Quando tento conectar através do cliente Android, recebo a seguinte mensagem no servidor:

> tun0: Here comes a new tunnel

e logo depois a mensagem:

> tun0: The tunnel is broken

e não consigo me conectar no servidor VPN.

Aqui está o tutorial com os comandos dentro do exemplo do android.

```
// # Enable IP forwarding
// echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
//
// # Pick a range of private addresses and perform NAT over eth0.
// iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
//
// # Create a TUN interface.
// ip tuntap add dev tun0 mode tun
//
// # Set the addresses and bring up the interface.
// ifconfig tun0 10.0.0.1 dstaddr 10.0.0.2 up
//
// # Create a server on port 8000 with shared secret "test".
// ./ToyVpnServer tun0 8000 test -m 1400 -a 10.0.0.2 32 -d 8.8.8.8 -r 0.0.0.0 0
```